# a freeware software to limit my kids time on the PC

Tags: parental-controls

I am looking for a freeware software that will set a schedule and a time limit for the amount of time my kids are able to use the PC.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Vista and 7 have built-in Parental Control features, that include the ability to set per-user schedules for computer access.

Answer (score -1):

I also created my own software to accomplish the time limit function you requested that the built in parental control doesn't do. You can mix the built in parental control tool with my software.
My software can be found at http://digiparent.weebly.com/ Hope you like it!